# How to show group and grouped items within a frame Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Has anyone implanted something like the following, that could be of relevance to me? How can I put a frame that encompasses both the group and the items in the photo:

[[image: ListView Group with frame]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so3QY.png)

Comment: Have you tried the book of Ch. Petzold. The book is free to download. There is a section where he applies grouping to a list:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/

Comment: the question was not about the grouping, but how to apply a frame that would be over the group and the datatemplate

Comment: @GabrielRibeiroRossi -  did you manage to implement this? If yes, could you please share how did you achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I have a dirty but simple way:

When I make same forms I use ListView without grouping and ViewCell with RepeaterView. You need remember that it is not the best perfomance way.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to design the UI like the screenshot your provided, using frame to crop image, you can take a look:

```
<CollectionView IsGrouped="true" ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Frame Padding="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        BorderColor="Black"
                        CornerRadius="50"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        IsClippedToBounds="True"
                        WidthRequest="40">
                        <Image
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            HeightRequest="100"
                            Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                            WidthRequest="100" />
                    </Frame>

                    <Label
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Label
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        FontAttributes="Italic"
                        Text="{Binding Location}"
                        VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label
                    BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
       
    </CollectionView>
```

About viewmodel class, you can take a look [Xamarin.Forms CollectionView Grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping)

Comment: This does not work, even when copied+pasted exactly.  There is no frame around each grouping, which is what OP was asking about.